# Font-Change in PDFs created with TCPDF

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, pdf-generation, tcpdf

we create or invoice, etc. documents with tcpdf, which works fine so far.
Now we inserted a font with chinese characters for our customers in china. The first font looked a bit weired, so we switched to another. Adobe Acrobar Reader displayed it correctly but on my colleagues machine in Firefox it looks like the old font is still in use. Also on my dev browser (Chrome) I have this affect. On my Firefox it looks correct.
I already cleared the browser caches and deleted the file FNTCACHE.DAT - with no effect. I created also different pdf-files with different names.
What else could I do?

Thank you in advance,
Manu

Comment: OK, so far we believe that the internal Firefox/Chrome-PDF-Viewer is not able to display unembedded fonts correctly...

Comment: If those fonts are not embedded, that indeed may be the reason. PDF viewers are only required to know the standard 14 fonts (which do not contain Chinese characters).  Using any other font without embedding is asking for trouble.